Extracting username and hostname from Nix configuration (flake)
I'm new to Nix. I'm using nix-darwin on my Mac, and I have a basic flake. In there, I use darwinConfiguration.[my_host_name] = ... where [my_host_name] is replaced with a hard-coded copy of my computer's hostname. Since I want to keep this config on a public GitHub repo, I would like to extract this hardcoding out of my flake and instead use a variable imported from another file (that I can gitignore) like this: darwinConfiguration.${hostname}. I seemed to have gotten something to work when I did this:
# ./user.nix (is gitignored)
{
  username = "nixos-username" # Example username
  hostname = "nixos-hostname" # Example hostname
}

# ./flake.nix
...
outputs = input: 
  let inherit (import ./user.nix) username hostname;
  in
  {
    darwinConfigurations.${hostname}...
...
    users.users.${username} = {
      name = username;
      home = "/Users/${username}";
    }
...

While I was able to switch to this config, something seemed to have broken internally because darwin-rebuild and some nix commands don't work anymore ("no command found") and the zsh shell which I've configured via nix does not start (like it did before when I hardcoded my username and hostname).
I suspect it has to do with the way I've imported user.nix script and the way I used it to define my user.
How do I properly define this user.nix file to extract my username and hostname from the main config files?
